# How to redraw the console screen so it would appear as screen was cleared?

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal

So what I am trying to do it so simulate clearing screen of Eclipse terminal.

I know there isn't a real solution for clearing the screen so I know I must use tons of empty lines to clear the screen.

The problem is that when I do tons of new line characters the pointer would be at the bottom of the terminal.

How would I do this so I would end up with pointer at the top of terminal and entire view would appear clear of any text?

So it would look like Aircrack-ng like interface. The screen keep changing but only by scrolling down and updating the content, etc.

Comment: *"How to redraw the console screen so it would appear as screan was cleared?"*  For a 'professional' look, put a rich client desktop-app. on the screen, and show the output in that.

Comment: I'm sorry but which pointer are you referring to?

Comment: That doesnt look like a good solution. Have u tried using `Console.flush()` ?

Comment: It depends.  Is the Eclipse terminal a "real" terminal or a text component that is redirect the output of the Java process into it ??

Comment: Input pointer, I suppose. I haven't tried Console.flush().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want basically is to emulate the **clrtobot** `curses` function. Which:

> erase from the cursor to the end of screen. That is, they erase all lines below the cursor in the window. Also, the current line to the right of the cursor, inclusive, is erased.

In **window$**, there's the "cls" function, so you must use something like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

In most ***nix** there's the "clear" function. But please don't rely too much on this solution, because this varies, but you can use something like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");
```

I'm yet to see a solution non OS dependent.

I hope it helped. Cheers

Comment: `Runtime()` won't compile in Eclipse for some reason. How to make it compile?

Comment: Then I get some errors: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cls": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
 at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:39)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
 ... 5 more`

Comment: No, Eclipse under Windows 8.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't played with windows 8. Maybe the console have changed somewhat. Instead of "cls" try "cmd /c cls" and if doesn't work "command /c cls". Those are old school windows way of invoking a command through terminal. Give it a try, but it's untested

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c cls");` compiles but doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: I guess this is fine because I think it will work from Windows Command Line. Thanks.